# How to get parent entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6

I use JPA 2 with Hibernate. There are two entity classes, `CardElement` and `IdentityDocumentKind`. The last one is an inherited entity of the first one. SINGLE_TABLE inheritance strategy is used. When I try to select an instance of the parent class by query `from CardElement where id = '123456'` the following error occures:

> Object with id: 123456 was not of the specified subclass:
>   org.cp.cardsystem.CardElement (Discriminator: SDocClass)

I don't have a subclass for "SDocClass" discriminator value. Actually at the moment of developing `IdentityDocumentKind` class querying of `CardElement` was used widely across the application. So I can't create a subclass of `CardElement` for each discriminator value and replace `CardElement` with it in all existent queries. It would be cost too much efforts for me. Is there a way to instantiate parent entity class when SINGLE_TABLE inheritance strategy is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. I've annotated root entity class of inheritance hierarchy (`CardElement`) in this way: `@DiscriminatorValue(value = "not null")`. Now I can select objects of this class without creating subclass for each discriminator value. `not null` and `null` seem to be Hibernate's special discriminator values which match in discriminator column anything except null and null respectively. I've not found any information about these values in Hibernate's official documentation. So it could be some kind of undocumented feature.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly.  You are using Single Table strategy to store the whole inheritance hierarchy.  However, you have only mapped some of the discriminators, and this time, it is the unmapped discriminator causing the problem (because Hibernate dunno what that subclass means).  Am I understanding your problem correctly?

Consider work against a special DB view instead of the real table.  That view expose only records with discriminator you can handle.

Comment: Yes, you've understood my problem properly. But working with such a DB view instead of table would make all records with unmapped discriminator inaccessible through CardElement. It is important to provide a possibility to work with all existing data by CardElement entity class.

Comment: But how would you want to provide access? You don't want to create corresponding child class, then how are you supposed to give access?  Why can't you create a child for each value of discriminator (it is fine even it is just an empty class extending your parent), or, forget about inheritance for you whatever IdentityDocumentKind.  Just treat that field as an attribute

Comment: When creating IdentityDocumantKind I supposed it would be possible to deal with records which have unmapped discriminator as CardElement instances. I can create inherited entity for each discriminator value. But it will require to refactor a lot of code throughout all application where CardElement is already used to access data. This code had been already existed at the moment of developing IdentityDocumentKind.

Comment: You don't need to do any refactoring I believe, if you are just concerning data access.  Because each subclass inherits from CardElement, which mean, such subclass "is-a" CardElement.  User can still treat it as CardElement (that's the beauty of polymorphism isn't it?)

Comment: You're right. Refactoring isn't required. In my case it's enough to make a descendant for each discriminator value for now. At a first glance an existing code that works with CardElement isn't affected. Thanks for this nice idea. However this solution causes another potential problem. It makes impossible to create CardElement instance with a new discriminator value in runtime. All discriminator values must be defined in development time. Is there some workaround?

Comment: If you are using that field as discriminator to determine what is the child-type, it is natural that it is something cannot be handled in runtime.  If it is the case, why bother using inheritance then?  IMHO, to use hibernate effectively, you should always start from designing your models and create db schema accordingly.  If you start from db schema that sounds reasonable, it is not always possible to use hibernate effectively with that.  Some pattern or usage is reasonable and feasible in db-oriented thinking, but never suitable to map to object-oriented design (yours maybe one of them)

Comment: I started from existing db scheme mapped to object model in some improper way. That's why I had to search tricky ways to solve slightly weird problems. Anyway, thanks for your help. It was useful for me.